# Schema warning about QAPage on Question type

Tags: schema, schema.org

I have a page with multiple Question and Answers and I'm getting the following warning on each question:

`Missing a QAPage markup item on page to which this item should be associated.`

---

This is example markup:

```
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  <h3 class="question" itemprop="name text">This is the question?</h3>
  <div class="answer" id="IdForTheAnswer" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer">
    <div itemprop="text">
      <p>This is the answer text.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And below is the example warning from https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ :

```
Question | 0 ERRORS | 1 WARNING

@type
- Question
  - name    
    - This is the question?
  - text    
    - This is the question?
  - acceptedAnswer
      - @type   
        - Answer
      - @id 
        - https://www.example.com/IdForTheAnswer
      - text    
        - This is the answer text.
warning 
  - Missing a QAPage markup item on page to which this item should be associated.
```

---

What is this warning actually asking me to provide?

What I've tried unsuccessfully so far:

1. Remove the `id` from the `acceptedAnswer`
2. Use `suggestedAnswer` instead of `acceptedAnswer`
3. Provide the `Question` with a `mainEntityOfPage`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so after an entire day of trying I finally stumbled on the answer.

I was getting that same warning if I removed everything but the question item, so it's something related to that.  I tried a lot of things and on a hunch I ended up wrapping the whole collection of questions in this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FAQPage">
  <!-- Rest of Q&A markup -->
</div>
```

And now I get valid schema without any errors or warnings.

I feel like the documentation and error messages are not very good, or I just don't understand this ecosystem and its resources yet!

p.s. I also tried the `QAPage` itemtype but that requires a lot more props and doesn't actually describe the page I'm building, so `FAQPage` comes closest.